# How to fetch Firestore document that contains a reference to another document in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from a Firebase Database in Swift 5.  
I have two collections: "users" and "locations" (locations has a reference to user).  
I have attached a snapshot listener to the locations collection so I will fetch data every time.  there is a change and add it to a global array.
Therefore after I fetch the location document I want to also fetch the user that is referencing to.

I had to add a DispatchGroup so it will wait for all users to get fetched and added to the array before passing the array through the completion block.  
However, it is adding duplicates of each location into an array. How should I fix this problem? 
    Thanks in advance for your help :).

```
    static func startListener(completion: @escaping ((_ data: [Location]) -> Void)){
    db.collection(LOCATIONS_DOCUMENT).addSnapshotListener {
        (snap,error) in
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        if(error != nil){
            print(error!)
        }
        else{
            self.locations.removeAll()
            for location in snap!.documents{
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                let map = location.data()
                let id = location.documentID
                let image = map["image"] as! String
                let title = map["title"] as! String
                let latitude = map["latitude"] as! NSNumber
                let longitude = map["longitude"] as! NSNumber
                let userRef = map["user"] as! DocumentReference
                let user = User();
                userRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if(error == nil){
                        let userMap = document!.data()
                        let userId = document!.documentID
                        let userFirstName = userMap!["firstName"] as! String
                        user.id = userId
                        user.firstName = userFirstName
                    }
                    let newLocation = Location(id: id, image: image, title: title, latitude: Double(truncating: latitude), longitude: Double(truncating: longitude), user: user)
                    self.locations.append(newLocation)
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
        }
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(locations)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding any data in Location collection on same screen? @Radu04